# ethereumj and keystore file

Tags: keystore, ethereumj

I tried to create an account by using ethereumj client, It said it created it but I could not see the keystore file. Can ethereumj generate the keystore file just like go client?

Comment: What steps did you follow to create the account? What have you done to check whether the account was created? Where have you looked for the keystore file?

Comment: The json-rpc function in JsonRpc.newPersonal_account()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EthereumJ core doesn't have keystore functionality. All key oprations are made via `ECKey` keipair class. Though you always may utilize any Java Keystore implementation.